# How to execute the second function in C?

Tags: c, function

Whenever I enter the choice of **2**, it does not execute the **view_list()** function. Instead it start it from first function which is **new_acc()**. Also the **else** is not working. How to solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int new_acc();
int view_list();

int main(){

    int one=1, two=2;
    int new_account, list;

    printf("%d. Create new account\n",one);
    printf("%d. View customers list\n",two);

    printf("Enter you choice: ");
    if (scanf("%d",&one)){new_account = new_acc();}  // calling a function 
    else if (scanf("%d",&two)){list = view_list();} // calling a function 
    else {printf("Sorry this is not the correct option"); break;}
    return 0;
}

int new_acc(){
    char name;
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);

    return 0;
}

int view_list(){
    printf("view list");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (scanf("%d",&one))` I really doubt this is doing what you think it does.

Comment: scanf will return the number of input items assigned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of scanf() is the number of values it returns, not the actual value it self. Code should be:

```
int value = 0;
scanf("%d",&value);
if(value == one){new_account = new_acc();}
else if (value == two){list = view_list();}
else {printf("Sorry this is not the correct option"); break;}
```

Other recommendations:

1. The final `break` is not doing anything;
2. Indent your code it makes it much easier to read:

   ```
   int value =0;
   scanf("%d",&value);
   if(value == one)
   {
      new_account = new_acc();
   }
   else if (value == two)
   {
      list = view_list();
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Sorry this is not the correct option");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `scanf()` is number of data read.

```
printf("Enter you choice: ");
if (scanf("%d",&one)){new_account = new_acc();}  // calling a function 
else if (scanf("%d",&two)){list = view_list();} // calling a function 
else {printf("Sorry this is not the correct option"); break;}
```

should be like

```
printf("Enter you choice: ");
if (scanf("%d",&one)) != 1) { puts("input read error"); return 1; }
if (one == 1){new_account = new_acc();}  // calling a function 
else if (one == 2){list = view_list();} // calling a function 
else {printf("Sorry this is not the correct option"); return 1;}
```

or

```
printf("Enter you choice: ");
if (scanf("%d",&one)) != 1) { puts("input read error"); return 1; }
switch (one) {
    case 1: new_account = new_acc(); break;  // calling a function 
    case 2: list = view_list(); break; // calling a function 
    default: printf("Sorry this is not the correct option"); break;
}
```

By the way, executing your `new_acc()` is dangerous.
`%s` specifier will accepts positive-length string while your buffer has space for only one character.
Even input of one-character string will cause buffer overrun because there will be terminating null character.
It should be like

```
int new_acc(){
    char name[1024]; /* allocate an array */
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%1023s",name); /* specify length limit (buffer size - 1 (terminating null character)) to avoid buffer overrun */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I replace `%s` with `%c`?

Comment: @BilalKhan It is OK... At least it will eliminate the risk of buffer overrun.